# How can I build a binary image with random sequence of 80% 1s and 20% 0s?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to implement an algorithm for generating a binary image having random sequence of 80% 1s and 20% 0s in it with python-opencv.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: You create a list of 80% 1s and 20% 0s of the desired size and `random.shuffle()` it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use something like `numpy's` [`rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) method, then the following short code snippet should do the trick:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate image with random values
img = np.random.rand(400, 400)

# Binarize image manually, and convert to uint8
img[img <= 0.2] = 0
img[img > 0.2] = 255
img = np.uint8(img)

# Save image, and output white pixel percentage
cv2.imwrite('images/img.png', img)
print("Percentage of white pixels: ", cv2.countNonZero(img) / (400 * 400))
```

You will get an image like this:

[image: Output]

And/But, the percentage of white pixels might not be exactly 80 %:

```py
Percentage of white pixels:  0.798975
```

If you want to have an exact amount of 80 % white pixels, I guess, you will have to determine and set the right amount of pixels to white, and maybe shuffle them in a way, as the result then seems to be random generated. **EDIT:** Just like Klaus D. suggests in his comment.

**EDIT:** For completeness, here is a code using `numpy's` [`shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) method:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate black image (sequence)
img = np.zeros((400 * 400, 1), np.uint8)

# Determine number of white pixels, and set
img[0:int(0.8 * 400 * 400)] = 255

# Shuffle pixels, and reshape image
np.random.shuffle(img)
img = np.reshape(img, (400, 400))

# Save image, and output white pixel percentage
cv2.imwrite('images/img.png', img)
print("Percentage of white pixels: ", cv2.countNonZero(img) / (400 * 400))
```

The output image looks the same as above, but the percentage - for this image shape - is now exactly 0.8:

```py
Percentage of white pixels:  0.8
```

Comment: Nice answer. I'm intrigued as to why you didn't start with an array of random uint8 integers between 0 and 255 and just `cv2.threshold()` which would save 2 passes and a cast?

Comment: @MarkSetchell In fact, that was my first idea. But, for the given example `p = 0.2`, what would be the proper threshold? There are 256 values in `[0 ... 255]`, so I would need `51.2`, which can be hardly done using `uint8`. So, my impression was, thresholding at `0.2` in `[0.0 ... 1.0]` would be a bit more precise. Since this approach isn't very exact in general (see above), one could also go this route, especially considering it's faster/more efficient.

Comment: I agree, I just figured 1 in 256 was less than 0.5% error.

Comment: @HansHirse  Thanks for the code. But it is creating a gray-scale image. I need a binary image with pixel values 0 or 1. Can you tell me how can I convert it into a binary image?

Comment: @RahulSavsani I'm not aware of any image format to support this, especially dealing with OpenCV. So, when you want to save the image, you'll always have at least an 8-bit image, i.e. a grayscale image. If you just want to process this "image", you should use logical arrays from `numpy`, but then you'll get only `True` and `False` values, not `0` and `1`. So, to me, it's not really clear, what you want to achieve with this "image".

Comment: @HansHirse  Thanks for the reply. I've also got another question: When I'm extracting pixel values from this image, I'm getting arrays like [2 2 2] or [254 254 254]. As we have assigned the values to every pixel either 0 or 255, why m I getting pixel values other than 0 and 255?

Comment: @RahulSavsani During processing? After saving and re-opening? What do you exactly do (code)? I think, this will lead into a separate question. So, please ask a new question (maybe linking to this question and answer, if the context is necessary) describing your problem in detail there.

Comment: @HansHirse I'm getting this kind of pixel values after saving and re-opening the image file.

Comment: @RahulSavsani Do you save the image as (lossless) PNG like suggested? Then, I have no idea. Saving as JPG or (lossy) PNG might give artifacts in that fashion.

Comment: @HansHirse Thanks buddy. I've stored the image as JPG, that was the fault.